# What Syntax for file-based Smalltalks are there?

Tags: syntax, smalltalk

I know of GNU Smalltalk's Syntax that puts the method body surounded by square-brackets after the selector like so:

add: anObject [
 self tally add: anObject.
]

Are there other file based approaches?

Answer (score 9):

There is the chunk file format which is what GNU Smalltalk (GST) used to use, and which most other Smalltalks support as File In/Out format.  The contents of the Squeak sources and changes files are in this format.

Additionally there is the Smalltalk Interchange Format (SIF) which is specified by the [ANSI Smalltalk standard](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/uploads/172/standard_v1_9-indexed.pdf), which is similar to the chunk format but incorporates some additional metadata and structure.  I know that there is a reader for SIF in GST, but I'm not sure if VisualWorks or Squeak have readers for this format.

Answer (score 7):

There's the changeset (or `fileOut`) format (off a random changeset on my machine):

```
'From Squeak4.1alpha of 3 April 2010 [latest update: #9883] on 5 April 2010 at 11:41:27 am'!

!Browser methodsFor: 'initialize-release' stamp: 'fbs 4/5/2010 11:38'!
classListFrame: bottomFraction
    ^self
        classListFrame: bottomFraction
        fromTop: 0
        fromLeft: 0.25
        width: 0.25.! !
```

Answer (score 3):

> The Resilient programming language
>   differs from Smalltalk in the
>   following ways ... We introduce a full
>   syntax for classes to allow
>   programmers to use standard tools for
>   program manipulation and source
>   control management.

p5 [Design, Implementation, and Evaluation of the Resilient Smalltalk Embedded Platform](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.7354&rep=rep1&type=pdf) pdf

Comment: Resilient Smalltalk uses apparently the same syntax that SOM uses (both coming from Århus). See http://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/projects/som/ for details on SOM.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the mentioned syntaxes there are the following, I am aware of:

- Coral: http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/coral/
  A syntax extension for scripting with Smalltalk (Pharo)
- SOM: http://github.com/smarr/SOM/
  A minimal file-based Smalltalk
- Pepsi: http://piumarta.com/pepsi/pepsi.html
  Another file-based Smalltalk dialect, but with prototypes instead of classes.

Answer (score 2):

GemStone/S filein sytax is described in the [Topaz Maual section 1.13](http://community.gemstone.com/download/attachments/5308874/GS64-Topaz-2.4.pdf?version=1)

Answer (score 2):

I should also mention the [Cypress package format](https://github.com/CampSmalltalk/Cypress/blob/master/README.md) which is currently shared by 6 different Smalltalk dialects:

- Amber (Cypress)
- Cuis (Cypress)
- GemStone (FileTree)
- Pharo (FileTree)
- Squeak (FileTree)
- VW (STIG)

The Cypress package format should be relatively easy to port to additional dialects....

Answer (score 1):

The read of sources is part of the `fileIn` procedure, that is used to communicate systems. The format for `fileIn` can change while reading, because the `fileIn` stream can contain new classes and methods, that when evaluated in the reader, teach the system e.g. on how to read the following data.
The `fileIn` is a method designed to sync (objects=data&behavior of) systems.
More information can be found in http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/U8/277
and use cases are frequent using S8 (see http://u8.smalltalking.net ) in systems development for web and mobile.